# Swfit 4 JSON adding custom header

Tags: json, swift, request, swift4

How can I add custom header while sending GET request on server.
I have tried

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: URL)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    //        request.addValue("2", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-version")
    request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

P.S I am beginner so if there is any mistake please point it out and help me to improve. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are adding it in the right way, except for adding Authorization header field. Apple says you should not do that. Whats the issue you are having with it?

Comment: I was unable to get my data and it used to throw 401 Unauthenticated error

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to authenticate to the API using a token, you set the wrong format for the `Authorization` header. Token authorization is also called "bearer authorization", the format is below:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!
let token = "abcdef"

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
    guard let data = data else { print("No data"); return }

    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
    }
}.resume()
```

You don't need the `Content-Type` header since a GET request has no body content.

Comment: I just tried again using your code snippet, still got authenticated error.

Comment: What API are you using? The documentation will usually tell you how to authenticate with it

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
func setHeader() -> [String : String] {
    let dictionary = [
        "Accept":"application/json",
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Authorization": "your_authtoken"
        // more headers here
    ]
    return dictionary
}

// calling
request(endPoint, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers: setHeader())
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help and is Content-Type is necessary?

Comment: are you using alamofire ?

Comment: actuall i delivered ans compatible with `Alamofire`, for this you just need to install `pod ‘Alamofire’` and import the lib where you want o use and go with my ans ..

Comment: I was looking answer for without using any library. Anyways thank you for your help.